# Does the size of a text node affect the speed of DOM traversal?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom

I have a pretty large single page application that's about 800K. About 500K is data that's sent to the client. I'm considering moving some of my elements that are just json strings in the head in the `<script>` tag.

When the browser traverses the DOM, does it also look in the `<head>` tag (in which case there would be no benefit) of does traversing occur only inside the `<body>` tag?

Comment: The size of the text in your script/div/whatever tags doesn't matter when traversing the DOM (eg. by applying a selector query). It's a Document *Object Model*, you don't do a string search :-)

Comment: @Bergi, imagine about 5,000 divs, some with 10 levels of hierarchy, being traversed and modified.

Comment: You said your data were mostly JSON strings, not a complex page?

Comment: It's both: lots of json data wth lots of divs, mostly created at runtime

Comment: Why do you have divs with JSON content at all? I guess they are not to be shown at all. Shouldn't you have one big JSON file with the data, and then create a independent visualisation at runtime?

Comment: The json data is injected into the page when it's created on the server; sends one big HTML file, in one request, plus one js file, one reference to jquery and 1 css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `document.querySelectorAll("some selector example")`, elements in the head are also considered. This can easily be solved by using:

```
document.body.querySelectorAll("...")
```

The same applies to `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementsByClassName`, `querySelector`, etc.
But not to `getElementById`, since an id must be unique within a document, so limiting the context wouldn't make sense.

Text is also a node type, by the way. `<script> ...500kb... </script>` generates the following DOM tree:

```
SCRIPT
    #text
```

Comment: So whether the element is in the head or in the body makes no difference?

Comment: @frenchie No, it should not matter. When put in the head, it might take more time before your page looks "available". If put in the body, the browser will be able to process some already-loaded content.

Comment: @frenchie Here's a JSPerf, by the way. It doesn't show a significant performance difference: http://jsperf.com/textnode-size-and-dom

Answer (score 0):

I would try and restructure how the data comes back from the server if you can, rather than shifting the contents into places that may or may not get parsed by the browser.

Perhaps have a quick response that just returns the basic information and then a fuller response in response to another request.

I do also have a web service that can create that amount of data.  **800K** is about the limit for me too but I have made the endpoints a little more specific to limit that data.

Cheers
Glenn